# Can you send a variable to the CSS in a Web Part

Tags: typescript, sass, sharepoint-online, spfx

I have created some SPFx web parts for SharePoint Online.
I call my styles by doing this ...

```
import styles from '../styles/CustomWebParts.module.scss';

this.domElement.innerHTML = `
    <div>
      <div class="${ styles.customWebParts }">
        ${await this.getGroupData()}
      </div>
    </div>`;
    
    }
```

Then I get a string back like this ...

```
stringToReturn += "<figure style='min-height:" + this.properties.iconHeight + "px;max-height:" + this.properties.iconHeight + "px;min-width:" + this.properties.iconWidth + "px;max-width:" + this.properties.iconWidth + "px;' class='" + styles.snip1212 + "'>";
```

Is there a way to not use inline styles when I want to pull a value from a web parts properties?

Thanks
P

Comment: Depends on the framework that you are using. If, for example, it was an angular component you could have the Value in a property of the component. The quick and dirty solution would be to get a reference with the getElementById method and extract the value

Comment: I'm using React in some (but not all) web parts. Some have no framework.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Having dynamic css? Then why you not just create a style tag (document.createElement("style")), then add your custom css to the style element (styleElement.innerHTML = ".classNameHere { height: 50px }"). The string you set as inner html is something you can change like you want depending on the values you get from the webpart properties for example.